# A question in proof of result that there are infinitely many primes of form $8a-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am self studying  number theory from David M Burton and I have a question in theorem on page 182 of 7 th edition whose image I am adding below. 
[image]

I am unable to understand why if all odd prime divisors are of form $8k+1$ then $N$ must be of form $8a+1$ . Why didn't the author considered even divisors of $N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(8a+1)(8b+1) &= 64ab + 8a + 8b + 1  \\
    &= 8(8ab+a+b)+1  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so a product of any quantity of numbers having the form $8n+1$ is another number of the same form.

The proof is to show there is an odd prime of a certain form.  The only possible even prime divisor of $N$ is $2$ (appearing with power $1$), which is of no use in showing the existence of the desired odd prime.

Comment: I am confused as N =$ ( 4p_1...p_n)^2  $-2  not just $p_1... p_n$ , how are you sure that multiplying by 16 and then subtracting 2 will have no impact on N?

Comment: argument used by author is N becomes of the form 8k+1  but I don't see it how!!

Comment: @TimGreen : Do you not see that the product of two numbers 8a+1 and 8b+1 is of the form 8k+1?  It's right there in the first display.  Then induction shows the product of a list of numbers of the form 8k+1 is a number of the form 8k+1.

Comment: @TimGreen : There is no requirement that the proof slavishly follow Euclid's argument to find a new prime.  All the proof has to do is show, by *any* means, that there is a new prime not on the list.  The proof accomplishes this by using their $4(p_1\cdots p_n)^2 - 2$.

Comment: The result is derived from the fact that all prime factors of $N=a^2-2$ are either $1$ or $7 \pmod 8$ (this follows from quadratic reciprocity), and if $a$ is odd, then $a$ and $N$ are coprime. It also follows that $N=7\pmod 8$. Therefore, there always exists a prime $p = 7 \pmod 8$ that is not divisible by $a$. The proof result is similar to  Euclid's proof for infinite primes in general.

Comment: @EricTowers can you please help me with this question if you have some time to spare. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621731/a-question-regarding-change-of-index-of-summation-in-analytic-number-theory